# Is there a more pythonic way to write this?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to make this a little more pythonic.

```
user_df[-1:]['status_id'].values[0] in {3,5}
```

I ititially tried `user_id.ix[-1:, 'status_id'].isin([3,5])`, but didn't work.

Any suggestions? The top version works, but looks a little weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
user_id['status_id'].iloc[-1:].isin([3,5])
```

Sample:

```
user_id = pd.DataFrame({'status_id':[1,2,3]})
print (user_id)
   status_id
0          1
1          2
2          3

#iloc without : [-1] return scalar
print (user_id['status_id'].iloc[-1] in set({3,5}))
True

#iloc with : [-1:] return vector - Series
print (user_id['status_id'].iloc[-1:].isin([3,5]))
2    True
Name: status_id, dtype: bool
```

Comment: very good answer. especially if he really really wants to use pandas `isin` for this (as indicated in his question)

Comment: Yes, great answer. I opted for `user_id['status_id'].iloc[-1].isin([3,5])` just to maintain consistency. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`isin` might be marginally faster (the more values that you have to check the more speed up you would notice ... but even for large sets its not going to be a huge difference ...(I doubt its any faster in this example... its probably a little slower) ... but `val in set()` **is pretty dang pythonic** (in fact much more so than `pd.isin`)

you are testing a **single value** against a `set` ... by using `pandas.isin` or `numpy.in1d` you will incure significant time overhead to move into C and back to python vs just using `in` and a set wich is an `O(1)` look up ... (*in either case the time slice is non-existent on a human time scale*)

Comment: and also pandas function handling `NaN` very well

Comment: but i dont think that applies to this problem domain ... he is testing a **single value** against a set ... NaN is not in that set

Comment: I think generally pandas functions vs python functions. But in this way you are right.

Comment: And maybe another question is pythonic vs pandaic ;)

Comment: @jezrael: "pandorable".

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso - it is nice word ;)